# beautifulsoup parsing error in python -- junk characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

**Code - not sure what I did to make BeautifulSoup (BS) not work**

```
import mechanize
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#create a browser object to login
browser = mechanize.Browser()

#tell the browser we are human, and not a robot, so the mechanize library doesn't block us
browser.set_handle_robots(False)

browser.addheaders = [('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:9.0.6')]
#url
url = 'https://www.google.com.au/search?q=python'
#open the url in our virtual browser
browser.open(url)
html = browser.response().read()
print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.prettify())
```

**Error**

```
HTMLParseError: junk characters in start tag: u'{t:1}); class="gbzt ', at line 1, column 42892

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-AU"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>python - Google Search</title><style>#gb{font:13px/27px Arial,sans-serif;height:30px}#gbz,#gbg{position:absolute;white-space:nowrap;top:0;height:30px;z-index:1000}#gbz{left:0;padding-left:4px}#gbg{right:0;padding-right:5px}#gbs{background:transparent;position:absolute;top:-999px;v
```

Comment: You seem to be hitting errors because youre pulling in css in the html and its trying to parse it as HTML. Theres a similarish question here that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401110/using-beautiful-soup-to-convert-css-attributes-to-individual-html-attributes

Comment: @yoshiserry the code runs fine for me, what version of python are you using?

Comment: 2.7? should I install lxml parser? maybe?

Comment: maybe is the mechanize command getting the css and html, where as beautofulsoup(bs) would normally just be getting html?

Comment: @yoshiserry, I am using 2.7 also with no issue, your script gets and prints  everything fine.  Do you just want to parse the page?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to practice using beautifulsoup to parse the page and get links, or divs, or a, or href elements out of it.

if you, and I have 2.7 why does it work for you but not me? when same code?

Comment: @yoshiserry I added an answer, try using requests and see how you get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#url
url = 'https://www.google.com.au/search?q=python'
r=requests.get(url)
html = r.text
print html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: wow great thanks it works. i'm so confused as to why beautifulsoup doesn't work though.

Comment: it does using requests, but not beautifulsoup on it;s own, it spits out junk characters apparently that I downloaded.

Comment: maybe I didn't install it properly some other modules I installed from chris's binary packages aren't working either. I'm looking at you pyQt4

Comment: does the requests library have the ability to force the page to wait until its all downloaded (javascript generates some page content dynamically) I would like to scrape the dynamic content which the javascript generates.