# compute the average height and the average width of div tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have need to get the average div height and width of an html doc.

I have try this solution but it doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
average_width = np.mean([div.attrs['width'] for div in my_doc.get_div() if 'width' in div.attrs])
average_height = np.mean([div.attrs['height'] for div in my_doc.get_div() if 'height' in div.attrs])
print average_height,average_width
```

the `get_div` method return the list of all div retrieved by the `find_all` method of beautifulSoup

here is an example :

```
print my_doc.get_div()[1]

<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:81px; width:127px; height:9px;">
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">Journal of     Infection (2015) 
    </span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDB+AdvTrebu-B; font-size:8px">xx</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">, 1</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDD+AdvPS44A44B; font-size:7px">e</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">4
    <br/>
    </span>
</div>
```

when i get the attributes, it works perfectly

```
print my_doc.get_div()[1].attrs

{u'style': u'position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:81px; width:127px; height:9px;'}
```

but when i try to get the value

```
print my_doc.get_div()[1].attrs['width']
```

I get an error :

```
KeyError: 'width'
```

but i don't understand because when i check the type :

```
print type(my_doc.get_div()[1].attrs)
```

it's a dictionary , `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: are u using numpy mean? can u give url or more html source of the page?

Comment: @SIslam , I have edited my post

Comment: How do you calculate the width of a `div`? Example: I have a `div` set to 100% width. If my window is fullscreen, it's presumably ~1900px. If my window is smaller, the `div` is smaller. So what is its width? How does the notion of 'average' come in?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist, in the html input, the width and the height are specified for all div within the style attribute, for all div it's the same unit measurement, so i just need to get those values and compute the mean /average , the mean  will be used as a reference value to remove some useless fragment in this document , so  the screensize have nothing to do with it

Comment: `attrs` is a single entry dictionary with key `style` and the value being *a string containing the text width**. You have to parse the string yourself to extract the width attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be better way-

**Way -1**

Below is my tested code to extract **width** and **height**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:81px; width:127px; height:9px;">
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">Journal of     Infection (2015) 
    </span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDB+AdvTrebu-B; font-size:8px">xx</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">, 1</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDD+AdvPS44A44B; font-size:7px">e</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">4
    <br/>
    </span>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')    
my_att = [i.attrs['style'] for  i in soup.find_all("div")]
dd = ''.join(my_att).split(";")
dd_cln= filter(None, dd)
dd_cln= [i.strip() for i in dd_cln ]
my_dict = dict(i.split(':') for i  in dd_cln)
print my_dict['width']
```

**Way-2**
Use regular expression as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271365/how-to-pull-out-css-attributes-from-inline-styles-with-beautifulsoup).

Working code-

```
import numpy as np
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<div style="position:absolute; border: textbox 1px solid; writing-mode:lr-tb; left:45px; top:81px; width:127px; height:9px;">
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">Journal of     Infection (2015) 
    </span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDB+AdvTrebu-B; font-size:8px">xx</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">, 1</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDD+AdvPS44A44B; font-size:7px">e</span>
    <span style="font-family: EICMDA+AdvTrebu-R; font-size:8px">4
    <br/>
    </span>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'html.parser')    
my_att = [i.attrs['style'] for  i in soup.find_all("div")]
css = ''.join(my_att)
print css
width_list = map(float,re.findall(r'(?<=width:)(\d+)(?=px;)', css))
height_list = map(float,re.findall(r'(?<=height:)(\d+)(?=px;)', css))
print np.mean(height_list)
print np.mean(width_list)
```

Comment: Actually it does work because the key is 'style' instead of 'width' for the dictionary , i ve try the solution of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401110/using-beautiful-soup-to-convert-css-attributes-to-individual-html-attributes:
`import cssutils
a = cssutils.parseStyle(my_doc.get_div()[1].attrs['style'])
print a['width']`
but i get this error :
`ERROR Property: Invalid value for "CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 3" property: textbox 1px solid [1:20: border]
WARNING Property: Unknown Property name. [1:47: writing-mode]`

Comment: Same Here! Yes that may  be a custom tag which python library does not have!