# Is there any way to get all the "inner html text" of a website and its corresponding coordinates using python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pytest-selenium

I'm able to get the div elements by using this code:

```
divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div")
```

and by looping through the divs and using .text attribute I'm able to get the text as well

code:

```
for i in divs:
            print(i.text)
```

but in my use-case I want the location as well as the size of the text.
Please help !!

My code:

```
for i in range(0,len(WEBSITES)):
        print(timestamp()) #timestamp
        print(i,WEBSITES[i]) #name of the website
        driver.get(WEBSITES[i])
        delay = 10
        time.sleep(delay)   
        img = cv2.imread(os.getcwd() + '/' + str(i)+'.png')#read the image to be inscribed


        print("getting div tags \n")
        divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div")# find all the div tags
        # anchors = divs.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")#find all the child tags in the divs

        for i in divs:
            print(i.text.location)
```

Whenever I try .location or .size attribute I get Unicode error.

**Disclaimer: I have searched through all the post so this is not a duplicate question.**

Comment: I don't understand why people are unnecessarily down-voting the question without even properly reading the question.

Comment: what do you mean by `the size` ? `len`?

Comment: I meant width and height. similar to element.size attribute in python selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151188/compute-the-average-height-and-the-average-width-of-div-tag

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη that post is for beautiful soup, I'm looking for method in python selenium. and moreover if you read my question correctly i want coordinates of the text not the div.

Comment: Well programmatically , how do we understand that you are talking about `width` and `height` which you stated on your question that you want the `text` size which is refer to `len` function. so edit your post.

Comment: in your comment you said that you want coordinates of text but in your question `I'm able to get the div elements by using this code:` << here you talking about `div`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη read the full question, what is written at the end "but in my use-case I want the location as well as the size of the text. Please help !!" << You are not reading the question properly

Comment: My question gives the full walk through of the process taken by me, so that the others could get the proper context of the question.

Comment: Check answer below :)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I'm checking. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try getting the coordinates of the div rather than the text. Like below.

```
for i in divs:
     print(i.location)
```

**Edit**

So if you want to get the text coordinates of all text in a page, get the text elements in a page like below and get their coordinates.

```
textElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//body//*[text()]") #Gets all text elements
   for i in textElements:
      print(i.text)
      print(i.location)
```

Comment: i'm able to get the coordinates of the div but i need the coordinates where the text is present

Comment: Can you post the html. You are not able to get coordinates of text because it is not webelement.

Comment: i want to write a simple code in python selenium which open a website say for example "makemytrip" and scrape out only the text which are visible with their corresponding size and coordinates of the point where they are present.

Comment: In the specific case of "makemytrip" I'm able to fetch coordinates and size of "<a>" tags but since there are image as <span>tag as the child of <a> the coordinates will be for image as well as the text, but I just need the coordinates of the text and the code must be generic so that it can be applied to different websites.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly. Please check.

Comment: You saved my day i was actually looking for this snippet "//*[text()]". Thanks a lot. It will be much appreciated if you could upvote my question as some people here don't know how to use stackoverflow